# How to improve the quality of graphics made in R when they are copied to the clipboard as metafiles in R studio?

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2, export, metafile

when I make graphics in `R`, I use specific settings for aesthetics. Saving graphics as `PDF` maintains the quality of almost all elements. But when I copy the graphics, as a `metafile` to the `clipboard` to use them in `.doc` or `.docx` documents, I lose all quality, even when I save the document as `PDF`

```
library (ggplot2)

Source <- c(rep("Water", 12), rep("Oil", 12))
Range <- rep((c(rep("First", 4), rep("Second", 8))),2)
Xaxis <- c(0,1,2,5,0,1,2,5,10,20,30,40,
           0,1,2,5,0,1,2,5,10,20,30,40)
Yaxis <- c(0,1,2,5,0,1,2,5,10,20,30,40,
           0,1,2,5,0,1,2,5,10,20,30,40)

DF <- data.frame(Source, Range, Xaxis, Yaxis)

#plot
p <- ggplot(data = DF, aes(x = Xaxis, y = Yaxis)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(Range~Source,
             scales = "free")

#Aesthetic settings
theme_set(
  theme_bw() +
    theme(line = element_line(colour = 1, size = 0.125),
          rect = element_rect(colour = 1, size = 0.125),
          text = element_text(colour = 1, size = 8),
          axis.title = element_text(face="bold", size = 8),
          axis.text = element_text(colour = 1, size = 8),
          axis.ticks = element_line(colour = 1),
          legend.title = element_text(face="bold", size = 8),
          legend.title.align = 0.5,
          legend.background = element_rect(fill = NA),
          legend.box.background = element_rect(colour = 1),
          panel.border = element_rect(colour = 1),
          strip.background = element_rect(colour = 1),
          strip.text = element_text(colour = 1, size = 8))
)

update_geom_defaults("point", list(size = 0.8))
update_geom_defaults("smooth", list(size = 0.125))
update_geom_defaults("linerange", list(size = 0.125))

p
```

**In the R studio internal viewer**

[image]

**Plot saved as PDF (desired quality)**
[image]

**Plot copied to the clipboard as a metafile and pasted into a `.docx` document**

Crooked lines, different point sizes than expected. These aesthetic defects are maintained even when saving the .docx document as PDF
[image]

Comment: Is copy/pasting from RStudio a must? What about saving as a nice high quality raster graphic like a PNG and inserting or copy/pasting that file into Word?

Comment: `ggsave()` and Insert Picture.

Comment: In short:  don't do that.  As other's mentioned, it is much more preferred to save as a picture with `ggsave()` and insert into your document - save as PNG and then you can just work with it as a picture file.  You can also use a Markdown file to generate a Word document directly with the graphics embedded.

Comment: You might also look into the `officer` and `rvg` packages, which allow you to save vector graphics directly into a [new] word doc.